# Why is my custom adapter not working when I am trying to instantiate it?

Tags: java, android, instantiation

I have been trying to get this custom adapter to work but for some reason it doesn't. I tried to create the new adapter called `ItemAdapter` but it says that the symbol cannot be resolved when hovering over "ItemAdapter". It says that the `ItemAdapter` constructor is never used, even though I try to invoke the constructor. Any ideas why?

FoodDrinks

```
    public class FoodDrinks extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listviewitem);

        //create new array list to hold food and drink items
        ArrayList<NewItem> obj = new ArrayList<>();

        //add new items to array
        obj.add(new NewItem("Name", "Description", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        obj.add(new NewItem("Name", "Description", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        obj.add(new NewItem("Name", "Description", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        obj.add(new NewItem("Name", "Description", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        obj.add(new NewItem("Name", "Description", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, obj, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.l1);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

ItemAdapter

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewItem> {
private int mImageResource;
private ArrayList<NewItem> obj;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewItem> obj, int imageResource) {
        super(context, 0, obj);
        mImageResource = imageResource;
        this.obj = obj;

    }
```

Comment: import item adapter class in foodDrinks activity

Comment: Display full `ItemAdapter` class if possible so that we can give proper solution.

Comment: I had the itemadapter class in the wrong folder for some reason. Realized this as I tried to import it. So simple! Thanks!